# Send terminal input data when restarting a program (python)

Tags: python, terminal, restart

My script asks for input from the terminal first thing:

```
ans = raw_input("Do thing A (1) / Do thing B (2)")
```

Then runs the code and restarts itself when an exception arises.

```
def restart_program():

    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
```

The problem is I would need a human to input the option again so I tried this:

```
def restart_program():

    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, '1', * sys.argv)
```

But it didn't work. How can I send the option when restarting?

Comment: Wrap it in a shell script.

Comment: Though it's really odd to *restart* itself when there's an exception. A normal while loop inside the script will handle this much better.

Comment: As Evert said it would be better to wrap it in bash script. However, you might want to consider handling this exception. Could you tell us what kind of exception it is?

Comment: The script inserts data into a database by days. So it will try 01-01-2016, then 02-01-2016, etc. if I get a database exception, because of credentials for example, I want it to try again from the beginning after waiting 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like others mentioned in comments, try to run your python script via shell script using while loop, smthng like (first run wo cmd line arguments):

```
arg=''
while true
do
    python restart.py $arg
    arg='1'
    sleep 1800 
done
```

and in your python code check if argument was provided:

```
try:
    ans = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    ans = raw_input("Do thing A (1) / Do thing B (2)")
```

You just need to exit your program after exception you are handling raises not to restart it from your code.